# Should one square both sides of the equation $\sqrt{1+2\sin{2x}}= \cos{x}-\sin{x}$ in order to solve it, or is there a better way?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

We have $\sqrt{1+2\sin{2x}}= \cos{x}-\sin{x}$

Fistly my conception was squaring both sides but I figured out that this method is wrong, so my question is how should look solution this example ?

Comment: Squaring both sides is good. We do have to examine the roots we get to see whether they really satisfy the original equation.

Comment: but how to obtain the same result as [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2B2sin%282x%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29%3Dcosx-sinx)

Comment: Programs and people solve problems in different ways, it is not a good idea to try to emulate *Alpha*. For one thing, it "likes" to travel through the complex numbers.

Comment: What's wrong with complex numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squaring both sides gives

$$1+2\sin2x=\cos^2x-2\cos x\sin x+\sin^2x=1-\sin2x$$

or

$$\sin2x=0$$

This suggest $x=k\pi/2$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, but care must be taken to eliminate the ones for which $\cos x-\sin x=-1$ instead of $+1$.  That leaves $2k\pi$ and $(4k-1)\pi/2$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: why just for $\cos{x}-\sin{x}=-1$ shouldn't be $\cos{x}-\sin{x} \ge 0$  ??

Comment: @Gregor, when $x=k\pi/2$, $\cos x-\sin x=\pm1$.

Answer (score 2):

Well why not square it?
$$\sqrt{1+2\sin2x}=\cos x-\sin x\\1+2\sin 2x=\cos^2x-2\cos x\sin x+\sin^2x\\1+4\sin x \cos x=1-2\cos x \sin x\\6\sin x\cos x=0 \implies x=\frac{k\pi}{2}$$
NOTE:I used identities $$\sin 2x=2\cos x\sin x\\\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$$